# Coda slider crapping out after 12th slide item

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, transition, coda-slider

I'm using the [coda slider](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/) on my website http://joelglovier.com for featured work. All was well until I got past 12 slide items, at which point the transition effect sort of wigs out.

Instead of transitioning smoothly to the next slide, as it does for each of the first 12 slides, each slide after the 12th transitions by going all the way back to the first slide and then sliding all the way to the slides past 12.

Any clue why this is happening, or how I can resolve it apart from using only 12 slides? I've seen it work on [other sites](http://www.madebythomas.com/) with more than 12 items, so it must be an issue with my implementation.

EDIT: I'm seeing the behavior on Chrome (newest build)
EDIT2: to clarify, I see the behavior not just on Chrome, but also on Safari and Firefox.

Comment: I can see the error but can't spot a problem with the Coda code. I did notice a Javascript error on page load regarding the navigation. Perhaps there is a conflict there somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade jQuery from your current use of 1.4 (latest) to 1.5.2:

Change line 33 (in the rendered HTML):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Doug! See, it would be as simple as upgrading my lib version. But then again, that's why you're part of the jQ team!